# How much plastic pellets does it take to make 1 kg of filament? (making my own 3D filaments)

Tags: filament

Maybe this is a stupid question, but is 1 kg of plastic pellets equivalent to 1 kg of filament? I want to extrude my own filament using recycled plastic pellets. I want to know the cost of my material in general, so I was wondering if 1 kg of plastic pellets result in 1 kg of filament (regular spool)? How much plastic pellets are needed get 1 kg of filament?

Comment: Hi @Deborah, and welcome to the 3D printing group.  Questions may be on-topic or off-topic, but they are never "stupid" when asked with good intention.

Comment: As Fred.u said - if the extruder has a large reservoir, you may lose that much material once in each run.  E.g. if the reservoir uses 10 g, then you lose 10 g no matter whether creating  100 g or  10 kg of filament in a single run.

Answer (score 3):

If you ignore losses due to production machinery, your one kilogram of pellets will provide you with nearly one kilogram of filament. There may be some small loss of material stuck in the auger and drips from the nozzle and any place you discover plastic that is not on the spool.

How many plastic pellets does it take to make one kilogram of filament? One kilogram plus a bit more. If you are asking about the numerical quantity of pellets, how much does one pellet weigh? Are they large pellets or small pellets?